# Unable to open the physical file "database_log.ldf" Operating system error 32

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio, ssms

I have a problem with Visual Studio and SSMS. I want to open a `.mdf` database file in Visual Studio and SSMS at the same time. But every time I run my C# application, I get this error:

[image]

I have to go to SSMS and right-click on the database and click on 'detach' to resolve the problem. but its a very hard work.

Please help me. I've searched several times but that's not fixed.

Thanks

Comment: As suggested change the path or file name

Comment: It seems you are trying to attach the same mdf database file to different SQL instances at the same tine. This is not possible since SQL Server requires exclusive access to the data files. To access the same database from both SSMS and VS, you could attach it using SSMS and change your VS connection string to connect to the same SQL Server instance you use in SSMS.

Comment: I've attached the database in SSMS and change my VS connection string to connect to the same SQL Server instance. but the problem still not resolved @DanGuzman

Comment: @MohammadGh, make sure the VS connection string omits `AttachDbFilename`.

Comment: @DanGuzman how can I do this?

Comment: Change the the connection string as I mentioned. Exactly how depends on where you store it. For example, change the string in your app.config file.